# Andengine - any missing FPS causes other scene entities to slightly shake as it chases a fast entity

Tags: android, performance, camera, andengine, smooth-scrolling

I am creating an Andengine game and I copied this SmoothChaseCamera class from the Andengine development book I bought.

```
package com.killercoolgames.djdestiny.custom.andengine;

import com.killercoolgames.djdestiny.MainActivity;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.SmoothCamera;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;

public class SmoothChaseCamera extends SmoothCamera {

private static final MainActivity MAIN_ACTIVITY = MainActivity.getInstance();

private IEntity chaseEntity;

public SmoothChaseCamera(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    super(x, y, width, height, 3000f, 1000f, 1f);
}

@Override
public void setChaseEntity(IEntity chaseEntity) {
    super.setChaseEntity(chaseEntity);
    this.chaseEntity = chaseEntity;
}

@Override
public void updateChaseEntity() {
    if( chaseEntity != null ) {
        // Always follow the entity and the camera's centerY will be slightly ahead of the entity.
        setCenter(getCenterX(), chaseEntity.getY() + MAIN_ACTIVITY.CAMERA_HEIGHT / 3);
    }
}

@Override
public void reset() {
    super.reset();
    set(0, 0, MAIN_ACTIVITY.CAMERA_WIDTH, MAIN_ACTIVITY.CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    setCenterDirect(MAIN_ACTIVITY.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2, MAIN_ACTIVITY.CAMERA_HEIGHT / 2);
}

}
```

It does work correctly and everything and when I turn off all parallax layers and collision detection in my game, It does run at 59.80 FPS or higher normally on my real Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 device. If I make the chaseEntity have a high velocity of 300f or higher. The entity is moving pretty fast and the camera does follow it, but I notice a jut/shake occur every second on all entities on the scene except the chased entity. If I reduce the velocity down to 50f or less, I still get the same FPS, but because I am going slower, you do not notice the shake at all. I do believe that the camera is following correctly, because there is no jittering when looking at the chased entity, but if i look at any other objects in the scene, they jitter as the camera moves.

The problem is I need the entity to go fast because he is flying fast, and the level should end when he hits a certain Y. Ive tried adjusting other entities in the scene to account for the speeds. Ive tried slowing down the player and increasing the enemies speed and the issue still occurs. I am creating a game where you are constantly flying upwards as you move past enemies in the scene. The camera is super smooth following the entity it is chasing always. It is just the other entities in the scene seem to not be updating smoothly.

I have tried disabling everything to see if I could hit 60FPS and I think its not possible to hit everytime, which makes sense. I think it is the camera causing the issue but I am not sure. The moment I start to turn other stuff on in the game, my lag does go up abit to 59.50 FPS or higher but sometimes it will still stay the same around the 59.80 consistently with all stuff on, and it kind of tells me its the camera not being able to keep up. Is this the case? How to fix this?

After doing some debugging today, I do believe its just any lagging FPS left that does not make it to 60FPS is what is causing the lag. I am not sure how to fix this. I am using a PhysicsHandler to update the sprites position for the camera to follow. I tried doing a MoveModifier and still had the same issue. I cannot figure out a way to keep the camera moving upwards smoothly.

I even tried doing a FixedStepEngine and with that, it make the lag consistent but I could never actually get rid of it. It always was there but much worse when switching to a FixedStepEngine.

Comment: Did you try to use fixed step engine?  Also I think I had similar issue once, I slightly changed camera speed values and it helped.

Comment: I just added in a FixedStepEngine and I tried it with some different values for steps, I tried 60, 55, 30 and at least the lag is not random. But it seems to make it worse. I did notice that the lag times are consistent at 60. So maybe this is telling me that when I dont use a FixedStepEngine. The .20 FPS remaining from a 59.80 FPS is causing the lag I am seeing? Do you know specifically what fixed yours?

Comment: Turns out to be device lag more than anything I think, tested on my mother's phone which was newer and faster and the jitteriness is real small. Also jitteriness on a huge tablet, is way more noticeable and gives a headache, I was able to reduce it slightly with tweaking camera speed values. No way to really get rid of it though. Good news it phones wont really see it unless they are older and slower.